# Drush over local network share?

Tags: drush

Can drush be run on a site when I have the server connected to my machine as a network share? I am running Win10 and the server is Windows based with IIS. The website folder mounted as a drive, so the path to it is something like Z:\website.

I noticed that I can switch between Acquia DevDesktop sites by changing the cmd line path (ie. from c:\devdesktop\site1 to c:\devdesktop\site2)

Can I essentially do the same by changing over to z:\website?

My thinking is that getting everything setup as if the webserver were remote (what most install tutorials asume) seems overkill. But, I am not really sure what DevDesktop is doing to get drush running on it's sites.

Is anyone doing anything similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory yes. Windows is a bit more difficult because, windows.

But if you have Drush installed locally, and it's the same PHP version as you have on the server machine it should work. You will need to modify your DB credentials to reference your database by network accessible hostname or IP so that your machine can connect to the database on the server remotely.

Disclaimer: I've never tried this, but it should work. YMMV etc.

The more "right" way to do this would be to set up an ssh server on the windows box server, and set up Drush aliases to act against the remote server with Drush installed locally on the server and client.

I don't know how well that works on Windows but quick reading suggests it should be possible.

Comment: Thanks. Will give it a go. 

Mostly curious if someone answered with a flat-out 'no, can't do it' so I wouldn't spend time on it.

Comment: @jnd Did you succeed? I am in a similar situation now. I am on MacOS and got access to an IIS server via smb. There's no SSH connection available and thus I am stuck. In the terminal, I can `cd` to the server and the Drupal root folder. I can then call `drush status` but it doesn't return anything.